# How to put exe file in windows Startup

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have WPF Application. I want to give ability  for user by checkbox to put App (exe file) to the windows Startup. How Can I do this programmaticaly in C#?

Comment: had same question.. :-) stackoverflow rocks. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add the application to the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` key in registry. See this for an example in C#: [Managing Start-up](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Trayminimizer.aspx#Managingstart-up10)

Answer (score 1):

You can add your program to the registry, the folder would be `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]`. You do this by adding a new string value, eg. `"Notepad"="c:\windows\notepad.exe"`.

[A short guide](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/registry-ins-and-outs-using-c/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding it for reference only as question already answered.

These are all possible locations to register application in startup.

```
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\Run
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunServicesOnce
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunServices
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnceEx
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce\\Setup
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunEx
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run
```