# How to make an exe start at the Windows Startup

Tags: c#, windows, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put exe file in windows Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012151/how-to-put-exe-file-in-windows-startup)

Suppose I have built an application in C#, Once I install it, I want it to run in the background whenever windows starts up,or you can say a user logs in to his windows account. Is there any way I can do that? Except writing a windows service?

The application basically shows messages when a certain event is triggered
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012151/how-to-put-exe-file-in-windows-startup

Comment: @GSGuy I disagree since the other question is directly related to WPF.

Comment: It's a duplicate, but this question has better answers.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add to shortcut to Windows start-up folder:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
```

Or add to registry, something like this:

```
RegistryKey add = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
add.SetValue("Your App Name", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");
```

You can change CurrentUser to LocalMachine if you want it to run with every user. Thanks to Aidiakapi.

Comment: Note that you could change the Registry.CurrentUser to Registry.LocalMachine to enable it for every user. +1 for example code. Another note: You could use: `@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"` instead of: `"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"` to void the escaping of the `\` character.

Comment: @Badr... Forgive me for my ignorance, do I have to put above mentioned lines of code, in my C# application code...I am lost:S. Will I be able to verify that the exe actually will start at windows startup?

Comment: WPF has not ExecutablePath proprerty.

Comment: How to add parameter for launch command? `myApp.exe --hidden true --fastbootmode true`

Comment: What of those is the preferred/recommended way to do this? I don' t know too much, but seems like adding it to the registry may be the proper way.

Answer (score 13):

This can be done using the windows registry. I recomend you to check this registry keys.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
```

Comment: +1 For registry use, a lot more professional in my option then using the Windows startup folder.

Comment: Thank Aidiakapi :D  and... Any reason for the received Downvote?

Comment: Probably, because he wanted votes while you were earlier. I think StackOverflow should disable the vote down on questions you've answered yourself.

Comment: I'm Agree with you. We're here for helping people, not for the points or badges. This situations should be prevented.

Answer (score 2):

You could add your application to the registry to run on startup at

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
or
`HKEY_CURREN_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

or you could add it to the startup folder for the system.

These are probably the most common/easiest options if you do not want to write a service.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up a new key in the registry pointing to your executable.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

More information in this link
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to put it or a shortcut to it in `%userprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startupdirectory` or `%allusersprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

The registry keys `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (all users) and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (current user only) will also serve.

Installing it as a service is often a good approach, but not if you're going to be interactive as you say.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the `Path` to the executable in the `Registry`

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

And it will get executed every time you start windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a shortcut to the application in `C:\Users\@username@\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Are you using Visual Studio Setup Project? If yes you can set the shortcut directly from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well this really sounds like you should use a "windows service".

There are other options like including a shortcut to the EXE into the "Startup" folder in the Programs Menu ("All Users" if you want it to run for all users on that system).

Another option would be to use the windows registry. You could add an entry to "Run" which points to the exe:

```
* HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
* HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Comment: Shouldn't be a service if it shows messages; services should be non-interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one else has mentioned it, I'll point out that you can also achieve this using a Scheduled Task who's trigger is 'At System Startup'. However, I haven't tried this with an app that needs UI interaction - it works for a background process, but I suspect it wouldn't work with something that needs a desktop context (since there isn't one until a user logs-on).