# c# autorun program when system starts gets error start manually works

Tags: c#

Hello guys I created program which starts on startup but it gets error that says :

> Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\Uribaani-Realm-Computer.ico'.

This file is installed in application folder.
When I start program mannualy everything works fine.

Code where program shows error on mindump debugger.

```
NotifyIcon icon = new NotifyIcon();
icon.Icon = new Icon("Uribaani-Realm-Computer.ico");
icon.Visible = true;
```

I add autostart program from question answered below :

[How to make an exe start at the Windows Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394098/how-to-make-an-exe-start-at-the-windows-startup)

Comment: Give me a reason why are you downvoting. Question is very simple!!!

Comment: Add an icon to app resources, instead of loading it from the hardcoded location.

Comment: It is in app resuorces

Comment: What is the start location set in the shortcut in the startup folder of Explorer (assuming you are using that method)? Unless set the initial current directory will be `c:\Windows\System32`. If not using a shortcut you'll need to work out the correct path relative to your executable.

Comment: Ben, based on that code, you are loading from a file.See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yt46ccy.aspx.

Comment: Question answered no need for futher investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current folder is "C:\Windows\system32" when it's run automatically, so that's where it's looking for the ico file. You will need to provide the full path to the ico in your code.

If the file is in the same folder as the exe, you can use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory. For example:

```
icon.Icon = new Icon(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Uribaani-Realm-Computer.ico"));
```