# different behaviour of azure devops agents on hosted vm when different computer access the vm

Tags: excel, powershell, azure-devops, remote-desktop

**Edit : After a lots of testing, we managed to find a comon point between the machines which, when connected using RDP to our environment, breaked the excecution of excel funtionnalities called from a powershell script launched by an azure devops agent : All these machines have a touchscreen, machines without a touchscreen do not break it (tryed with 3 machines with touchscreen, different contructors and 4 machines without touchscreen)**

***Edit 2: When the touchscreen is disabled being connected to the machine with RDP do not break the script anymore***

I'm using AzureDevops agents to execute a powershell task on a Cloud Hosted environment, the task is very simple it justs creates a workbook and saves it:

```
try{
    write-host 'initalized excel' 
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    write-host 'adding WB'
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
    write-host 'Saving Wb'
    $Workbook.SaveAs('C:\test\test.xlsx')
 }
finally{
write-host 'quitting excel'
$Excel.quit()
}
```

Here's the output of the devops Task :

```
##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.151.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\33ed6d09-53ba-427a-a7ac-ea425a98767c.ps1'"
initalized excel
adding WB
quitting excel
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At C:\agent\_work\_temp\33ed6d09-53ba-427a-a7ac-ea425a98767c.ps1:6 char:5
+     $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

This is what happens when my colleague is connected to the virtual machine on which the agent executes the script. My colleague is connected with the windows remote desktop tool.

When I'm the one connected on the VM using RDP it works fine :

```
##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.151.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\436b2d56-2a41-4f75-97bb-01d4c41407e6.ps1'"
initalized excel
adding WB
Saving Wb
quitting excel
##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

My colleage and I RDP to the virtual machine with the same exact user.

We tried on another virtual machine with another devops agent, the same issue arise.

I'm a bit lost and I dont know how to troubleshoot this issue at all, also if you have any other suggestion for the title I'll take every piece of advice.

Edit:

We also tried to put this script in a loop and write if it succeed or fail, when I rdp to the virtual machine, it works, if I disconnect it works, as soon as my colleague RDP into the virtual machine it starts failing, if I reconnect (thus disconnecting my colleague) it works again. (We RDP with the same user)

Edit2 :
I'm receiving an edit suggestion from someone who noticed me that :

> From the user's comment->' when the agent is already running and
>   creating excel  files in a loop, the simple fact my colleague rdp to
>   the vm breaks the excel file creation.'  This issue seems to have
>   nothing to do with azure devops. The reason for the problem is due to
>   rdp

Well it's an azure devops agent problem as well since simply running the script manually works for both of us. It's a RDP issue that cause the Devops agent to be unable to use some of the excel-powershell functions, so I think the Azure Devops tag is still accurate

Edit :

> In the finally block try outputting the full error stack with: $Error
>   | Format-List -Force – HAL9256

Here's the error :

```
Exception             : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BE): The remote procedure call failed. 
                        (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
                           at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, 
                        IntPtr errorInfo)
                           at System.Management.Automation.ComInterop.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 
                        hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, ComMethodDesc method, Object[] args, UInt32 argErr)
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject )
                           at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
                           at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at 
                        System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame 
                        frame)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\agent\_work\_temp\fae3ef7a-700d-49c1-8f1f-7f7d2bc0d49e.ps1: line 8
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Comment: I am not quite sure, if I understand the question.  You use an Azure DevOps Build Agent. Why do you RDP to the agent machine?

Comment: to check the excel file creation and use some other programs, but I do not think it's revelant, could you tell me what you didnt understand so I can fix it ? @SebastianSegerer

Comment: Are you running the agent as a service?  Or are you and your coworker starting the agent in a console window while you are RDP to the machine?  Have you tried creating an excel document at that path using the account the agent is running when it doesn't work?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT The agent is running as a service, what do you mean by "starting" the agent on a console ? I was not aware it could be done, do you have a documentation I could follow ? Also as stated in my question, when the agent is already running and creating excel files in a loop, the simple fact my colleague rdp to the vm breaks the excel file creation. Simply pasting the script in a powershell console works fine with either me or my colleague

Comment: @Maxime Sorry, my previous description is not accurate.I mean: Run this script directly in the local environment of vm (i.e. with powershell), can it run successfully?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT the script runs perfectly when we just copy-paste it to powershell, with either me or my colleague connected

Comment: In the `finally` block try outputting the full error stack with: `$Error | Format-List -Force`

Comment: Also, is there differences in your RDP connection settings. i.e. Local Resources -> connecting local drives i.e.`C:`

Comment: @HAL9256 I'll have my colleague try with the full stack error, our RDP connection setting are the same, we both removed every shared ressources from the configuration to see if it mattered and it didnt

Comment: Maybe a strange question, but why do you remote desktop into the server? Can't you leave the server alone, or run the agent in a Windows Container you can easily recycle?

Comment: is there a reason for you to use an excel workbook ? alternatively you can perform a CSV manipulation ?

Comment: @jessehouwing to be honnest it's not even a blocking problem, we just gave another machine to my colleague and it works fine when he rdps from this new machine, but I like to understand why things behave the way they do

Comment: @VenuraAthukorala the goal is to generate an excel report on other actions performed by the script and sent it by mail, so csv is not an option

Comment: @HAL9256 I added the error logs at the end of the question

Comment: Wow... Touchscreens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally identified that the problem only happened when using the RDP from a laptop having a touchscreen.

We then disabled the touchscreen using this documentation :

> 1. In the search box on the taskbar, type Device Manager, then select
>      Device Manager.
> 2. Select the arrow next to Human Interface Devices and
>      then select HID-compliant touch screen. (There may be more than one
>      listed.)
> 3. Select the Action tab at the top of the window.
> 4. Select Disable device or Enable device, and then confirm. If there's more
>      than one HID-compliant touchscreen device listed, perform steps 2–3
>      for that one too.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028019/windows-enable-and-disable-your-touchscreen-in-windows-10

And the script stopped crashing.

If someone want to post an answer to solve this problem without disabling touchscreen by tweaking the parameters in RDP or in the server we RDP to, i'd accept his answer as it's easier to change the parameter once than to ask people to disable their touchscreen when they rdp to our machine.

Answer (score 2):

### [Running Excel under an automated, unattended process (such as an Azure DevOps Agent) in unsupported and can lead to all kinds issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office), like the ones you are running into.

The official recommendation is to rely on a 3rd party component like [Excel Package Plus (free)](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), [NPOI (free)](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI), [SpreadSheetGear (Commercial)](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) or [Aspose Cells.NET (Commercial)](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net). Or to use `System.IO.Packaging` and [edit the XML for the Office document directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging?view=netframework-4.8). These do not depend on having Excel installed on your server, are actually supported and don't have all kinds of license issues associated with them. Migrating your scrips over to these other package types is often not very hard, since they take a very similar API for portability.

Besides the technical issues you're running into, the licensing may be even hairier, as Office isn't allowed to be automated 'on behalf of other users' and generally isn't allowed to run on a server.

> Besides the technical problems, you must also consider licensing issues. Current licensing guidelines prevent Office applications from being used on a server to service client requests, unless those clients themselves have licensed copies of Office. Using server-side Automation to provide Office functionality to unlicensed workstations is not covered by the End User License Agreement (EULA).
>
> <sup>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office</sup>

You may be able to solve some of the issues, like the one you are experiencing now, but you're likely going to run into new ones. Running the Azure DevOps agent interactively may help, that way Excel will be launched in the interactive session as well, instead of a protected hidden user session with no real desktop. What's likely happening, is that the second user connecting over RDP is closing all other sessions when they log on, or locking all sessions as they log off.

> here are security risks when you enable automatic logon or disable the screen saver because you enable other users to walk up to the computer and use the account that automatically logs on. If you configure the agent to run in this way, you must ensure the computer is physically protected; for example, located in a secure facility. If you use Remote Desktop to access the computer on which an agent is running with auto-logon, simply closing the Remote Desktop causes the computer to be locked and any UI tests that run on this agent may fail. To avoid this, use the tscon command to disconnect from Remote Desktop. For example:
>
> ```
>  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe 1 /dest:console
> ```
>
> <sup>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#interactive-or-service</sup>

Another problem concerning excel automation on a server, is that existing Excel instances are re-used. This may cause the host excel to run under different credentials than the process doing the automation.

---

To run the agent interactively configure the serves to [auto-logon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows) ([this utility encrypts the credentials used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon)) and [add `run.cmd` in the agent folder to the start-up executable list (either in the registry or a shortcut in the start menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394098/how-to-make-an-exe-start-at-the-windows-startup)). [You can also make the agent executable (`c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c path\to\agent\run.cmd`) the default shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms838576(v=winembedded.5)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). [There are quite a few docs on setting a custom shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher).

You'll need to disable the screensaver and lockscreen for this session as well, which well require you to physically secure the server, otherwise anyone with access to the servers console will be able to access the running interactive session.

And you must unsure you always disconnect the remote desktop session without locking it (like above).

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer, but I still do not understand who the machine which rdps to the environment might break the execution of the script while any other machine rdping to the environment doesnt break it. The "second user" locking sessions is a nice theory but the user orders doesnt seem to matter, only the machine my colleague is using seem to break the script

Comment: We finally identified the root cause, see my edits in my questions, I'm not able to dig deeper, but if you have any ideas

Comment: You should really check out Excel Package Plus! It has made my life easier on many occasions.